# how can i write several else in CASE When Clause in SELECT (MYSQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to write something like

```
if(?) x elseif(?) y else z
```

and also I want to use CASE WHEN  FOR THIS.

Comment: And what trouble is that giving you?

Comment: Mysql manual describes the syntax for case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySql has `IF(cond, true, false)`. You can nest them.

So you can do `IF(a, x, IF(b, y, z))` for `if(a) x elseif(b) y else z`

You can also write

```
      CASE WHEN a THEN x
           WHEN b THEN y
                  ELSE z END
```

to do the same thing.  Pretty straightforward.  Some other makes of DBMS server use `IIF()` instead of `IF()`.